# event.preventDefault() only works the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, preventdefault, flask-socketio

I've been having trouble prevent the page from reloading when submitting the add channel form a second time. When the user tries to add a channel name that already exists, an error is displayed for the user and the form can be submitted again. However if you try to submit the form again, the page reloads and passes the form data to the browser, ex.: http://127.0.0.1:5000/?name=z&description=z&submit=Submit#

It should not reload the page, rather just fail and display an error again, or successfully add the new channel, however it does neither if the channel add fails, and the form is submitted a second time.

I don't understand why my second form for sending messages behaves as expected but not the new channel form.

main.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

var chatWindow = $('#chat-window');

// Connect to websocket
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    socket.on('connect', () => {
    //get all channels
    socket.emit('get channels')

    // get last channel
    socket.emit('select channel', {"channel": window.localStorage.getItem('channel')})

    //initialize buttons for New Channel, Submit New Channel, and Send Message
    const newChBtn = document.getElementById('show-new-channel-form')
    newChBtn.onclick = () => {
        document.getElementById('new-channel-form-div').style.display = 'block'
    }
    const newChForm = document.getElementById('new-channel-form')
    newChForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const name = newChForm.elements['name'].value
        const description = newChForm.elements['description'].value
        name && socket.emit('add channel', {'name': name, 'description': description});
        newChForm.reset()
    })
    const sendMsgForm = document.getElementById('send-message-form')
    sendMsgForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const message = sendMsgForm.elements['message'].value
        message && socket.emit('send message', {'message': message});
        sendMsgForm.reset()
    })

})
```

...  handling new channel add result:

```
socket.on('channel add failed', data => {
    const error = `<div class="alert alert-dark alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <strong>${data.error}</strong>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>`
    document.getElementById('new-channel-form').reset()
    document.getElementById('new-channel-form-div').innerHTML += error
})

socket.on('channel added', data => {
    document.getElementById('new-channel-form').reset()
    document.getElementById('new-channel-form-div').style.display = 'none'
    const newChannel = document.createElement('a')
    newChannel.className = 'dropdown-item dropdown-channel'
    newChannel.innerHTML = data.name
    newChannel.value = data.name
    newChannel.onclick = () => {
            socket.emit('select channel', {'channel': data.name})
        }
    console.log(newChannel)
    document.getElementById('channel-select-options').append(newChannel)
    socket.emit('select channel', {'channel': data.name})
})
```

forms in index.html

```
<div class="col" style="display: none;" id="new-channel-form-div">
                <form role="form" id="new-channel-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Channel name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Channel description">
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="channel-submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" />
```

...

```
    <div class="col-12" id="text-input-area">
        <fieldset>                      

            <form name="send-message" id="send-message-form" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" input rows="2" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="actions">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit your message." />
                </div>  
            </form>     
       </fieldset>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Instead of submitting the form the usually way, have you considered submitting it via the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)? This would address you priority of NOT reloading the page.

Comment: In addition to `event.preventDefault()`, you may need to return `false` in the event handle function for the if/then circumstances where you do not want the submit event to actually submit.

Comment: @LonnieBest I am trying to stick to using flask_socketio to communicate with the server.